# Netsuite REST API (Invalid Signature)

Tags: c#, netsuite

I am trying to connect to Netsuite from my C#.NET application using RestAPI. I have completed the following steps,

1. Setting up complete user, role, integration etc at Netsuite UI
2. Using the consumer key, secret, Token Key , Secret etc I have tried to create signature and send web request. Always I received the error as "Invalid Signature" (Found in Login Audit Trail)

   ```
        string NS_realm = "1234567";
        string url = "https://1234567.restlets.api.netsuite.com/app/site/hosting/restlet.nl?script=9&deploy=1";
        HttpWebRequest request = null;
        HttpWebResponse response = null;
        String header = "Authorization: OAuth ";

        try
        {
            string consumer_id = "<consumer key>";
            string consumer_secret = "<consumer secret>";
            string token_id = "<token Id>";
            string token_secret = "<token secret>";
            Uri uri = new Uri((url)); 
            OAuthBase req = new OAuthBase();
            string normalized_url;
            string normalized_params;
            string nonce = req.GenerateNonce();
            string time = req.GenerateTimeStamp();
            string signature = "";

            string baseString = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(NS_realm) + '&' + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(consumer_id) + '&' + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(token_id) + '&' + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(nonce);
            string key = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(consumer_secret) + '&' + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(token_secret);

            baseString = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(NS_realm + "&" + consumer_id + "&" + token_id + "&" + nonce);
            key = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(consumer_secret + "&" + token_secret);

            var encoding = new System.Text.ASCIIEncoding();
            byte[] keyBytes = encoding.GetBytes(key);
            byte[] baseStringBytes = encoding.GetBytes(baseString);
            using (var hmacSha1 = new HMACSHA1(keyBytes))
            {
                byte[] hashBaseString = hmacSha1.ComputeHash(baseStringBytes);
                signature = Convert.ToBase64String(hashBaseString);
            }

            string oauthVersion = "1.0";
            string signatureMethod = "HMAC-SHA256";

            // Construct the OAuth header       
            header += "oauth_version=\"" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(oauthVersion) + "\",";
            header += "oauth_nonce=\"" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(nonce) + "\",";
            header += "oauth_signature_method=\"" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(signatureMethod) + "\",";
            header += "oauth_signature=\"" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(signature) + "\",";
            header += "oauth_consumer_key=\"" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(consumer_id) + "\",";
            header += "oauth_token=\"" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(token_id) + "\",";
            header += "oauth_timestamp=\"" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(time) + "\",";
            header += "realm=\"" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(NS_realm) + "\"";
        }
        catch (Exception q)
        {

        }
        try
        {
            request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create((url));
            request.ContentType = "application/json";
            request.Method = "GET";
            request.Headers.Add(header);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

        }
        try
        {
            WebResponse response1 = request.GetResponse(); 
            HttpWebResponse httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)response1;
            Stream resStream = httpResponse.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(resStream);
            var result = sr.ReadToEnd();
            object ResultObject = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<object>((string)result);
        }
        catch (UriFormatException)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error forming request. Check tokens, URL, and NBN details.");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Server or connection error:\n" + e.ToString());
        }
   ```

I have added my code snippet for easier reference. Could anyone help me out on fixing this issue?

Comment: I am not sure exactly what "new HMACSHA1" is; but perhaps change this based on Suite Article 50996: "In 2021.1 no new solutions using HMAC-SHA1 signature method can be created. As of 2021.2, HMAC-SHA1 signature method will not be supported. You must update your solutions to use HMAC-SHA256 signature method.."

Comment: Hello Thanks.. But i have tried out HMAC-SHA256,  still same kind of issue i have faced. any other suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Please try the below code.

```
using System;
using System.Text;

using System.Security.Cryptography;
using SuiteTalkTBA.com.netsuite.webservices;

namespace SuiteTalkTBA
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string compid = "<netsuite_account_number>";
            string consumerkey = "<consumer_key>";
            string consumersecret = "<consumer_secret>";
            string tokenid = "<token_id>";
            string tokensecret = "<token_secret>";

            NetSuiteService _service = new NetSuiteService();

            TokenPassport passport = new TokenPassport();
            passport.account = compid;
            passport.consumerKey = consumerkey;
            passport.token = tokenid;
            
            RNGCryptoServiceProvider rng = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider();
            byte[] data = new byte[20];
            rng.GetBytes(data);
            int value = Math.Abs(BitConverter.ToInt32(data, 0));
            string nonce = value.ToString();
            Console.WriteLine("Nonce is " + nonce);
            passport.nonce = nonce;

            //computing for timestamp
            Int32 unixTimestamp = (Int32)(DateTime.UtcNow.Subtract(new DateTime(1970, 1, 1))).TotalSeconds;
            string timestamp = unixTimestamp.ToString();
            Console.WriteLine("Timestamp is " + timestamp);
            passport.timestamp = Convert.ToInt64(timestamp);

            //Computing for Signature
            string baseString = compid + "&" + consumerkey + "&" + tokenid + "&" + nonce + "&" + timestamp;
            string key = consumersecret + "&" + tokensecret;
            Console.WriteLine("Base String is " + baseString);
            Console.WriteLine("Signing Key is " + key);
            string signature = "";
            ASCIIEncoding encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
            byte[] keyByte = encoding.GetBytes(key);
            byte[] messageBytes = encoding.GetBytes(baseString);
            using (HMACSHA256 myhmacsha1 = new HMACSHA256(keyByte))
            {
                byte[] hashmessage = myhmacsha1.ComputeHash(messageBytes);
                signature = Convert.ToBase64String(hashmessage);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Computed Signature is " + signature);
            TokenPassportSignature sign = new TokenPassportSignature();
            sign.algorithm = "HMAC-SHA256";
            sign.Value = signature;
            passport.signature = sign;

            _service.tokenPassport = passport;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: gowtham prakash:  let me try this approach. But this is seems like WSDL approach?  Which version have u used?

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing your OAuth signature method or timestamp as parameters. This is likely not only behind the generation of an invalid signature but also is a requirement for NetSuite to parse out and validate your client/user tokens.

It is also recommended that you alphabetize the parameters before generating your signature. It does not matter for the auth header. It should look similar to this:

```
string baseString = "deploy=" + deploy 
+ "&" + "oauth_consumer_key=" + consumerKey 
+ "&" + "oauth_nonce=" + nonce 
+ "&" + "oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA256" 
+ "&" + "oauth_timestamp=" + timestamp.ToString() 
+ "&" + "oauth_token=" + tokenId 
+ "&" + "oauth_version=1.0&" + "script=" + script;
```

Answer (score 0):

For InvalidSignature, it has to ensure the hash is computed correctly.

Sample format (Pseudocode):

```
$base = $accountID + "&" + $consumerKey + "&" + $tokenID + "&" + $nonce + "&" + $timestamp
$key = $consumerSecret + "&" + $tokenSecret
```

With HMAC-SHA256 and it is encoded in base64.

For more info:
**Error Messages for the TBA Authorization Flow**
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E60665_01/netsuitecs_gs/NSATH/NSATH.pdf#page=63

Sample Parameter value
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E60665_01/netsuitecs_gs/NSATH/NSATH.pdf#page=55

For TokenPassport:
Field requirement:
| Field | Description |
| ----- | ----------- |
| account | Your NetSuite account ID. You can find this number at Setup > Integration > SOAP Web Services Preferences, in the Account ID field. |
| consumerKey | The consumer key for the integration record. This string was created when you checked the Token-based Authentication box on the integration record and saved it. This string is shown only one time, when it is first generated. If you no longer have this string, you can reset the credentials, as described in Regenerating a Consumer Key and Secret . |
| token | This is a string identifier or an ID of a token that represents a unique combination of a user, a role, and an integration record. This string can be generated in multiple ways. For details, see Manage TBA Tokens in the NetSuite UI . |
| nonce | This field should hold a unique, randomly generated alphanumeric string of 6–64 characters. |
| timestamp | This field should hold a current timestamp in Unix format. |
| signature | The signature is a hashed value. You create this value by using all of the other values in the TokenPassport, plus the appropriate token secret and consumer secret. Along with the actual signature, you must identify the algorithm used to create the signature. For details, see TokenPassportSignature . |

Sample base string
https://4647128-sb1.app.netsuite.com/app/help/helpcenter.nl?fid=section_4395630653.html&whence=#bridgehead_4398049137

`1234567&71cc02b731f05895561ef0862d71553a3ac99498a947c3b7beaf4a1e4a29f7c4&89e08d9767c5ac85b374415725567d05b54ecf0960ad2470894a52f741020d82&6obMKq0tmY8ylVOdEkA1&1439829974`